# MySQL Returning a value even if no result - IFNULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like a certain `value(55)` when there is no result in a *MySQL* `SELECT` *Statement*.

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
  <?php
include_once("JSON.php");
$json = new Services_JSON();


$con = mysql_connect("XXXXX.com", "XXXXX", "XXXXXX");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("XXXXX", $con);

$arr = array();
```

// The following statement runs but when i tried with IFNULL .. doesn't work...

```
//$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM partie WHERE statut = 'en cours' ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1");

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT IFNULL((SELECT * FROM partie WHERE statut = 'en cours' ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1),55)");


while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
    $arr[] = $obj;
}

Echo $json->encode($arr);

?>
```

Comment: For which column you want to use `IFNULL` function ???

Comment: No i want to get 55, if 0 rows are returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error, try `echo mysql_error();`

What you probably want is something like this:

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM partie WHERE statut = 'en cours' ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1");
if( mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0 ) {
    echo 55;
}
```

Comment: My code will echo 55 when no rows are returned. You are looking for `mysql_num_rows`

Comment: use `json_encode` function to convert an array of object to a JSON string

Comment: could you help me to implement properly your suggest in my code please?